# exit error 1 in installing php composer on windows

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

in installing composer get exit error 1 like below picture

[image]

please help me for fix this error.

note : PHP is installed by EasyPHP.

thanks

Comment: make sure php.exe stays in the path you told

Comment: How did you install PHP on your computer?

Comment: The problem is your php.exe, try reinstalling PHP